# AutoHotKey function to perform File-Rename without relying on sending F2 key code

Tags: autohotkey

I want define a custom hotkey to rename a selected file in File Explorer. So my new hotkey should behave exactly like the F2 key does by default. That is, when I press the hotkeys, the file name should be editable, allowing me to type a new name. However, I can't use the F2 key to cause windows to do this.

The reason is that I'm using the default hotkeys for something else. I am often running an application (unrelated to AutoHotKey) where the buttons in the UI are triggered using keyhooking for all of the F keys. The only suggestions that I can find on this are to have my custom hotkey use 'send' to raise the default key codes that would be associated with the action. This won't work, because I am using those hotkeys for something else. What I need is a solution that causes a file to be renameable *without* sending the F2 keycode.

```
 ^+!R::
Send {F2} ;This won't work for me
return
```

Comment: You could use COM to get the current selected file and then rename it programmatically, and not via just using normal Windows renaming. Is this something you'd be interested in?

Comment: @0x464e, yes, that sounds like what I was envisioning doing.

Comment: What is the COM command to rename the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the original hotkey can be used, just add `$` before the hotkey that you don't want to be fired by the send command. Also using app-specific hotkeys a good idea to minimize possible conflicts.
Try this:

```
#If winActive("ahk_exe Explorer.EXE") 

^+!R::
    send {F2}
return

$F2::
    send {down}
return
```

In case you have an application which scans the F2 key globally and unconditionally, and you cannot redefine it, there is not much you can do from within AHK. So ideally you should get rid of that application, and use e.g. AHK for same functionality, or find some workaround.
In this particular case the easiest workaround is alternative way to rename the file:

```
^+!R::
    send {AppsKey}
    sleep 100
    send {m}
return
```

Comment: This does not work, the behavior is no different than just pressing the F2 key. Pressing the ^+!R hotkeys still causes the keyhandler event in the application, which causes it to think that a button was pressed in the application. Also, the file is not renamable.

Comment: @BernoulliLizard ah, maybe I missed the point - so you have some other application which 'listens' to F2 globally, regardless of which app is in focus?

Comment: I just tried that, and this suggestion still does not work. Even if File Explorer is active, if the other application is running, it still sees the F2 key event and responds accordingly. What I need is some function or dll method that I can call directly to cause the selected file to rename.

Comment: As a side note, [`#If`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm) shouldn't be used, unless it's actually needed. [`#IfWinActive`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm) should be used in this case. You can read about the downsides of `#If` from the documentation. Though, of course in a small script like this you more than likely wont encounter any problems either way, but still good practice to use the intended #directive instead.

Comment: I see, so this automates Right Click->Rename. That's not quite as clean as what I was hoping for, but this works and gets it done. Thanks! FWIW, I'd love to change the way that app scans the F keys globally, but we aren't allowed to.